# сокрытие клавиатуры

Tags: android, клавиатура

Доброго дня!

Подскажите пожалуйста, пишу блокировщик экрана. Есть эффект - если засыпаем с активной клавиатурой, то она и на экране блокировки потом видна. (Как это вообше? Ведь другое приложение стало активным). Вот нужно скрыть ее, клавиатуру эту..

Применено:

1. при получении сигналов вкл и выкл экранавызывается:

   ```
   getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
   ```
2. в этом же случае вызывается

   ```
   View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
   if (view != null) {  
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
   ```
3. в манифесте у активити вписано

   ```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
   ```

И клавиатура упрямо остается на месте, поверх моего активити... как так-то?...

Comment: P.S. данный эффект постоянен, присутствует и на 4 и на 6 андроиде.